# pointer not referencing position correctly for image gallery touch algorithm

Tags: javascript, swipe

I am implementing a photo gallery on a mobile device and am working on the sorting algorirthm when the user `swipes right` or `swipes left`.

My understanding is that i should keep a pointer position to track which position im at. i also have a pos variable bc i thought id need to know the position point **but i believe having the pos variable is not needed**

Here's my current code:

```
var cnt=0;var ptr=0;var pos=0;
var total=10;
function newimageshow(dir){
  if(dir=='ltr'){
    if(pos==0){
      ptr=total-1;
   } else {
      ptr--;
   }
  } else {
    if(pos==0){
     ptr=0;
    } else {
     ptr++;
    }
  }
  if(pos==(total-1)){
    pos=0;
  } else {
    pos++;
  }
  alert(dir+" Ptr: "+ptr);
}

newimageshow('ltr');  // on swipe left;
newimageshow('rtl');  // on swipe right
```

**This is completely wrong, but my first attempt.**

Essentially, here's what should happen:

0 - Initial load of gallery with a pointer of 0

1  - User swipes right and the pointer should be 1

2  - User swipes left and the pointer should be 0

3  - User swipes left and the pointer should be 9 (total-1)

4  - User swipes left and the pointer should be 8

5  - User swipes right and the pointer should be 9

6  - User swipes right and the pointer should be 0

7  - User swipes right and the pointer should be 1

7  - User swipes right to total-1 and the pointer should be 9

8  - User swipes right and the pointer should be 0

Answer (score 0):

```
function newimageshow(dir){
  if(dir=='ltr'){
   if(ptr==0){
    ptr=total-1;
   } else {
    ptr--;
  }
 } else {
  if(ptr==(total-1)){
    ptr=0;
   } else {
    ptr++;
  }
 }
 var img=document.getElementById("imggall");
 img.src="/img/gall1/"+imgs[ptr];
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide some explanatory text? (Answer has been marked 'low quality'.)